# Apparent contradiction when manipulating conditional expectations

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

For a random vector $(T,S,\theta)$ with joint distribution $f(\cdot)$ define the following function (slightly abusing notation for the distributions ): $$E[\theta|T=x,S=y]=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} z \cdot f(x,y,z)dz}{f(x,y)}=\hat{\theta}(x,y)$$

With the above I can write:
$$
E[\theta|T=t,S\geq s]=\frac{E[\theta \cdot I\{T=t,S\geq s\}]}{\Pr[T=t,S\geq s]}
$$
$$
=\frac{E[\theta \cdot \Pr[T=t,S\geq s|\, \theta]]}{\Pr[T=t,S\geq s]}
=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} z \cdot f(z) \left( \int_{s}^{\infty} \frac{f(t,u,z)}{f(z)}\,du \right) \,dz}{\int_{s}^{\infty} f(t,u)\,du} 
$$
$$
=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{s}^{\infty} z \cdot f(t,u,z)\,du \,dz}{\int_{s}^{\infty} f(t,u)\,du}
 = \int_{s}^{\infty} \hat{\theta}(t,u) du
$$
So partially differentiating the above w.r.t the truncation point $s$ yields:
$$
\frac{\partial E[\theta|T=t,S\geq s]}{\partial s}=- \hat{\theta}(t,s) \qquad (\text{Result A})
$$

On the other hand, if I do not use the substitution and differentiate directly the integrals, I get:

$$
\frac{\partial E[\theta|T=t,S\geq s]}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial}{\partial s} 
\left( \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{s}^{\infty} z \cdot f(t,u,z)\,du \,dz}{\int_{s}^{\infty} f(t,u)\,du} \right)
$$
$$
=\frac{-\int_{s}^{\infty} f(t,u)\,du \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} z \cdot f(t,s,z)\,dz+f(t,s)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{s}^{\infty} z \cdot f(t,u,z)\,du \,dz}{({\int_{s}^{\infty} f(t,u)\,du})^2}
$$

$$
=\left(E[\theta|T=t,S\geq s]-\hat{\theta}(t,s)\right)\frac{f(t,s)}{\int_{s}^{\infty} f(t,u)\,du}
$$

Which seems a contradiction with (A). What am I doing wrong? I may be missing something trivial here...

Comment: Could you justify why $E[\theta \mid T = t, S \geq s]$ is the same as $\displaystyle \int_s^{\infty} E[\theta \mid T = t, S = u] \mathrm du$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I edited the question to give more details about the derivation. Thanks

Comment: The last equal sign before "So partially differentiating the above" uses the "fact" that the integral of F over the integral of G would be the integral of F/G. Unfortunately (or maybe, fortunately), this ain't so.

Comment: @Did: Of course! Thanks… I knew I was missing something trivial ;)